# Assign specific 8 bits to uint8_t

Tags: c, bit, biginteger

Is there a way to do an assignment like

```
uint8_t x = 0010 0010;
```

without bit shifting?

I am using c99.

I really want to make it static, because I'm not changing anything on this "number" so it would save me some lines of code.

Comment: write it in hex: `uint8_t x = 0x22;`

Comment: @alinsoar Really I have never tried because I couldn't find anything on the web.

Comment: There are no binary integer literals in standard C. There are some compilers providing an extension for that though such as `0b100101`

Comment: Constant expressions will be evaluated at compile time (on any sane compiler, even for debug builds), so you can just use bit shifts too, if hex numbers seem unclear. The build result should be identical either way.

Comment: @hyde Yyes thanks I will use hex I guess, `00100011` should be `0x23`?

Comment: One question. Any modern compiler which do not support 0b notation?

Comment: Yes, converting between hex and binary is easy (which is one reason why hex notation has been adopted by the computer community). Basically, every 4 bits directly translates to a hex character. It's more concise and readable to represent binary strings in hex: https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/binary-to-hex-converter

Comment: @P__J__ Looks like MSVC is not supporting.. https://godbolt.org/z/LZM-Tg

Comment: For some octal is easier... you convert to hex using groups of 3 bits `0b00100010 = 0b00_100_010` so it's `x =  042`

Comment: @EugeneSh. The error comes from the command line. It did not even start to compile the program :)

Comment: @P__J__ Lol. You are right.

Answer (score 1):

Create a header file called something like binaryliterals.h, then:

```
#define b0000_0000 ((unsigned char)0x00)
#define b0000_0001 ((unsigned char)0x01)
#define b0000_0010 ((unsigned char)0x02)
// etc...
```

If you hunt around on the internet, you'll probably find many examples of this.  I used to have one in my tool box, but it's probably in a box of archived hard-drives at the moment.  Faster to write it from scratch at this point.

Comment: Many embedded systems compilers have these.  There's probably a few of them that are open source.

Comment: Just don't create this manually. You *will* make a dumb mistake which causes a hard to track down bug. Use a script or c-program to create the header file.

Comment: @HAL9000, really?  You think that writing a script or program to generate these is likely to be less error-prone than hand editing?  Either way, make sure you write a unit test to independently verify correctness.

Comment: @jwdonahue, A script will probably get all values right, or all wrong. Not a difficult bug to catch.  A manually written file may end up in the worst case scenario, all values correct, except a seldom used one.

Comment: A proper unit test is going to catch that.  I can write or acquire the whole thing for all 8 bit values accurately in about 15 minutes.  How long will it take you to write that script?  The real effort goes into writing the unit test for the file.

Comment: Actually, a good peer review would also suffice and probably take less than a dozen dev hours to get to 5 nines probability of correctness.  It really is very simple.  My editor (SlickEdit) or even Excel can automate most of the work without having to write any scripts/programs.